# How would I solve the following question on matrix diagonalization and inversion?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, algebra-precalculus

"$$A = \begin{pmatrix}-1&-1&2\\ \:-3&-2&-3\\ \:0&1&-3\end{pmatrix}$$

$$B = \begin{pmatrix}0&1&2\\ 1&0&2\\ 1&1&1\end{pmatrix}$$

For A, find an invertible matrix P and a diagonal matrix $D$ such that$ D = P^{-1}AP$.

For B, find an invertible matrix P and a diagonal matrix $D$ such that $D = P^{-1}BP$."

I know how to diagonalize and invert a matrix but I am not sure how I would get the required $P$ and $D$ above. Should I rearrange the equation and then find each of them. Since their are two unknowns, I am a little confused.

Any help?

Comment: You’ve asked a couple of questions in short succession that are various parts of an basic exercise in eigenvalues and diagonalization. Based on this and your previous series of questions, I’d suggest reviewing the material first. It doesn’t appear to have sunk in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$P$ consists of eigenvectors of the matrix.

Suppose $v_1, v_2, v_3$ be linearly independent and they correponds to eigenvector of $A$ with eigenvalue $\lambda_i, i=1,2,3$.

Then $$A\begin{bmatrix} v_1 & v_2 & v_3\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix} \lambda_1v_1 & \lambda_2v_2 & \lambda_13v_3\end{bmatrix}= \begin{bmatrix} v_1 & v_2 & v_3\end{bmatrix}\operatorname{diag(\lambda_1, \lambda_2, \lambda_3)}$$